# dijit.CheckedMenuItem - Changing the checked value in runtime

Tags: dojo

This is how I create the dropdown menu with checkboxes using dijit.

```
        layerList.reverse();
    var menu = new dijit.Menu({
        id : 'layerMenu'
    });
    dojo.forEach(layerList, function(layer) {
        menu.addChild(new dijit.CheckedMenuItem({
            label : layer.title,
            id : layer.title.replace(" ",""),
            checked : layer.visible,
            onChange : function(evt) {
                if (layer.layer.featureCollection) {
                    //turn off all the layers in the feature collection even
                    //though only the  main layer is listed in the layer list
                    dojo.forEach(layer.layer.featureCollection.layers, function(layer) {

                        layer.layerObject.setVisibility(!layer.layerObject.visible);

                    });
                } else {

                    layer.layer.setVisibility(!layer.layer.visible);
                }

            }
        }));
    });

    var button = new dijit.form.DropDownButton({
        label : i18n.tools.layers.label,
        id : "layerBtn",
        iconClass : "esriLayerIcon",
        title : i18n.tools.layers.title,
        dropDown : menu
    });

    dojo.byId('webmap-toolbar-center').appendChild(button.domNode);
```

I can access the individual dijit.CheckedMenuItem at runtime when the onChange event fired because I know their id. Since dijit does not has a RadioButton for MenuItem, is there a way I can change the checked status in runtime. Using "this.Id" and "evt", I can know which one is being check/uncheck by the user. Technically I can try to uncheck the other checked items if necessary to simulate the radio button behavior.

Can someone tell me how I can check/uncheck dijit.CheckedMenuItem in runtime? What properties and functions I need to call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just set checked to false on the other CheckedMenuItem widgets

```
checkedMenuItemWidget.set('checked',false)
```

To uncheck any given checkedMenuItem.

Comment: Not so simple. I tried both the onChange and onClick. Using dojo.byId("[Id of CheckMenuItem]") seems to get me something but call .set('checked',false) gives me an error "Object doesn't support this property or method". I can also get to the menu by doing "var olayermenu = dojo.byId("layerMenu");" but I cannot get to the individual menuItem to try setting the checked value. Following the code in https://bitbucket.org/dojo/dijit/src/c7ff6018943f/CheckedMenuItem.js?at=default I can only get the checked attribute in onClick.

Comment: You need to use dijit.byId, not dojo.byId since you are manipulating widgets, not dom nodes.